# Launch android file explorer "MyFile" from android application

Tags: android

Is there any possible way to launch the Android file browser application (called MyFile on Samsung Galaxy S) from my application (i.e via intent)?
My apps stores data on the sdcard, and having an icon to go to the data directory directly would be a great feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is no standard file browser application in Android.

"My Files" is something Samsung has created for some of their products, and it is only available on Samsung devices. Other manufacturers may or may not have similar applications, but not the same. Regardless, there's no way to launch a default "file browser".